# Are there alternative libraries for Relay and GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, reactjs-flux, relayjs

Facebook announced [Relay and GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html). However, they are not available yet. Are there alternative libraries that accomplish similar goals that can be used today?

Comment: React Transmit is a Relay-inspired library that uses Javascript Promises instead of GraphQL. It follows the official Relay API: https://github.com/RickWong/react-transmit/

Answer (score 9):

There will be [Falcor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiO1f6h15c8) soon, but it also is not available yet.

Also there is some libraries like [Breeze.js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) and [JayData](http://jaydata.org/), which requires server to implement [OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/).

**UPD:**

Falcor was released at August 17, 2015. [Here](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/) is the official website. [Here](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor) is the source codes.

Comment: The Breeze.js does not solve anything related to graph, but is a good Javascript framework for client / server data management.

Comment: @wonderfulworld Breeze.js communicates using OData. This builds on REST to support $expand so that you can retrieve multiple records with a single query, and $select so you specify which attributes you want. So it does solve some of the same challenges as Graph. That said, GraphQL looks far more attractive and I wouldn't recommend trying Breeze.js / OData unless you've got a .NET backend (we tried it and it hurt).